# Ignite with spring data jpa use grammar IN

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, ignite

When I use JPA with `IN`, it cause some problem, how can I resolve it? Am I confused about the expression  `IN?[*]`. Thanks

```
ignite:2.7.6
spring jpa:ignite-spring-data_2.0
spring boot:2.0.9.RELEASE
h2:1.4.197
```

jpa method: List findByShipVisitIdIsIn(List shipVisitIdList); or findByShipVisitIdIn.

the first method 'findByArrivedTimeGreaterThanEqualAndArrivedTimeLessThanEqual' works fine

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "BerthplanShipVisitCache")
public interface BerthplanShipVisitRepository extends IgniteRepository<BerthplanShipVisit, String>, 
HdShipIdRepository<BerthplanShipVisit, String> {

List<BerthplanShipVisit> findByArrivedTimeGreaterThanEqualAndArrivedTimeLessThanEqual(Timestamp start, Timestamp end);

List<BerthplanShipVisit> findByShipVisitIdIsIn(List<String> shipVisitIdList);

}
```

the SQL is auto-generated by `ignite-spring-data` plugin, I guess its something wrong between `ignite-spring-data` and `h2`

issue track:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ""BerthplanShipVisitCache"".""BerthplanShipVisit""._KEY, ""BerthplanShipVisitCache"".""BerthplanShipVisit""._VAL FROM ""BerthplanShipVisit"" WHERE ((""BerthplanShipVisit"".""shipVisitId"" IN ?[*]))"; expected "("; SQL statement:
SELECT "BerthplanShipVisitCache"."BerthplanShipVisit"._KEY, "BerthplanShipVisitCache"."BerthplanShipVisit"._VAL FROM "BerthplanShipVisit" WHERE (("BerthplanShipVisit"."shipVisitId" IN ?)) [42001-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:217)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:555)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3518)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2433)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3252)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2574)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2370)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3252)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2574)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2370)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2291)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2133)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1946)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1919)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:463)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:311)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:694)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepare0(IgniteH2Indexing.java:539)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:509)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:476)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatementAndCaches(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2635)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I edit the source code org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery  prepareQuery method. In it,treat 'IN ?' to 'IN (?,?)' ,also the parameters flatten. That seems ok.